# EasyPHP: mySQL/PHPmyAdmin does not work anymore after setting root user password - Plugin '*8AA9864C904BBB2AC83C09FA1004AC23FB18F4E8' is not loaded

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, easyphp

This what happened in a local developer installation of EasyPHP:

1. i set the password trough PHPmyAdmin for the root user (because i need to have a password for a new user and it seems that if the root has no a password defined the password for new users is not saved)
2. in the config file config.inc.php I set the password as defined

```
      /* Authentication type */
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Soksunae123';
      /* Server parameters */
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
      /* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(mysql|information_schema|performance_schema|test|phpmyadmin)';
```

3. i restarted all the servers (and also, since it didn't work, i rebooted the windows system)
4. when i try to run PHPmyAdmin i get this error

[image]

5. if I try to access by console i get the same error  "#1524 - Plugin '*8AA9864C904BBB2AC83C09FA1004AC23FB18F4E8' is not loaded" obviously after editing the password
6. looking to the settings of PHPmyAdmin in EasyPHP main page it seems the pw is not set for root user (but it could be not true since when accessing by console i get the same error using the right pw)

[image]

any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a setting for every login where you can control what hosts that user can use to login. It's possible that when you set the root password, you might have also changed the allowed hosts to "%" (All Hosts), which blocks local login (your phpMyAdmin instance is probably running on the local machine). See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1102191) for a possible explanation as to why this occurs (I'm pretty sure it's right).

In a shell on the local server, try this to login as root with a password:

```
shell> mysql -u root -p
Enter Password:
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

If you see that last line, and you're sure you're using the correct password, it likely means that the root account can only logon from TCP, not local socket. You can explicitly connect over TCP with this syntax:

```
mysql -u root -p --host=127.0.0.1
```

If the loopback (127.0.0.1) address doesn't work, try your LAN IP instead. Once you're in, you can add a second root login that can only login from localhost, and optionally set the same (or a different) password. Docs on [account management via SQL commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.6/en/assigning-passwords.html).

More help [in the connection troubleshooting docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.6/en/problems-connecting.html).

Comment: thank you for your answer,but when i try from dos console as explained at point 5. i get the same error "ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin '*8AA9864C904BBB2AC83C09FA1004AC23FB18F4E8' is not loaded". Don't know if this is equal to an "access denied", but i don't think. And no, the problem is not the TCP because before changing the root password it was working fine.But you gave me a clue,probably i set the password for the root with host defined "%" instead of the one "localhost" or "127.0.0.1",if i well remember all the 3 hosts had a root user. how to roll back setting pw on localhost?

Comment: tried to be sure also mysql -u root -p --host=127.0.0.1 getting the same error

Comment: I've never used plugins for MySQL. Looks like other users have had the same problem with EasyPHP. Here is a potential fix: https://github.com/easyphp/easyphp-devserver/issues/81

Comment: it seems crazy patch, just becasue i added a password! :-O I will try other packages instead of EasyPHP. Thank you.